# Extract part of a filename shell script

Tags: bash, shell

In bash I would like to extract part of many filenames and save that output to another file.

The files are formatted as coffee_{SOME NUMBERS I WANT}.freqdist.

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in $(find . -name 'coffee*.freqdist)
```

That code will find all the coffee_{SOME NUMBERS I WANT}.freqdist file. Now, how do I make an array containing just {SOME NUMBERS I WANT} and write that to file?

I know that to write to file one would end the line with the following.

```
  > log.txt
```

I'm missing the middle part though of how to filter the list of filenames.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the 'sed' command.

Comment: Actually no. I was querying Twitter for a clinical research project that involves comparing tweets from different locations. Twitter hung about 5% into searching through 40k zip codes. But, since I loaded the zipcodes as a dictionary in Python (and so unordered), I only have the output files labeled by zipcode to figure out which zip codes I already searched at. I figured this was a good reason to learn something about shell scripting rather than doing it in Python.

Comment: Actually no = in response to Piort's HW comment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do it natively in `bash` as follows:

```
filename=coffee_1234.freqdist
tmp=${filename#*_}
num=${tmp%.*}
echo "$num"
```

This is a pure bash solution. No external commands (like `sed`) are involved, so this is faster.

Append these numbers to a file using:

```
echo "$num" >> file
```

(You will need to delete/clear the file before you start your loop.)

Answer (score 7):

If the intention is just to write the numbers to a file, you do not need find command:

```
ls coffee*.freqdist
coffee112.freqdist  coffee12.freqdist  coffee234.freqdist
```

The below should do it which can then be re-directed to a file:

```
$ ls coffee*.freqdist | sed 's/coffee\(.*\)\.freqdist/\1/'
112
12
234
```

Guru.

Comment: I meant to take out the leading underscore too so: 's/coffee_\(.*\)\.freqdist/\1/'.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers have indicated some necessary techniques.  This answer organizes the pipeline in a simple way that might apply to other jobs as well.  (If your `sed` doesn't support ‘;’ as a separator, replace ‘;’ with ‘|sed’.)

```
$ ls */c*; ls c*
 fee/coffee_2343.freqdist
 coffee_18z8.x.freqdist  coffee_512.freqdist  coffee_707.freqdist
$ find . -name 'coffee*.freqdist' | sed 's/.*coffee_//; s/[.].*//' > outfile
$ cat outfile 
 512
 18z8
 2343
 707
```